# how to get my while to update a string length in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to get this while loop working to remove all consonants from the front of the input word, but it goes through once and finishes, how do I keep this while loop going until all consonants are at the end of the word (Example: I want "switch" to be "itch + sw" and for it to, once the consonants are moved, add "ay" at the end to form "itchsway" Here is my code so far, I'm very new to Python so any help would be appreciated!

```
print("Pig Latin Translator Test!")
name = raw_input("What is your name?")
if len(name) > 0 and name.isalpha():
    print("Hello!")
else:
    print("That's not a name!")
word = raw_input("What is your word?")
word0 = word[0]
word0 = word0.lower()
n = 0
if len(word0) > 0 and word0.isalpha():
    word0proof = word0
else:
    print("That isn't a word!")
if word0proof in "aeiou":
    wordoutput = word + "yay"
    print (wordoutput)
else:
    print("Your word doesn't begin with a vowel")
if word0proof in "bcdefghjklmnpqrstvwxyz":
    word1 = word0proof
else:
    word0proof = word0proof
#Now get word1 to move all consonants to the back of the word and add "ay"
```

This is the part I'm having trouble with in the code

```
while word1 in "bcdefghjklmnpqrstvwxz":
    word1 = word[n:] + word0 + "ay"
    n = n + 1
    print word1
    word1 = word1
```

Aside from all the indention issues, I basically just stole the ideas at improving my code and got this (removed all the variables and and then borrowed the while statement provided with the vowel list)

```
print("Pig Latin Translator Test!")
name = raw_input("What is your name, friend?")
if len(name) > 0 and name.isalpha():
    print("Hello!")
else:
    print("That's not a name!")
word = raw_input("What is your word?")
VOWELS = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U")
if word[0] in VOWELS:
    word = word + "yay"
else:
    while word[0] not in VOWELS:
        word = word[1:] + word[0]
    word = word + "ay"
print (word)
```

Comment: Code seems very confusing can you please indent it correctly?

Comment: I don't know how to indent it correctly, it makes sense to me looking at it, but that's probably because I made it

Comment: The input validation isn't really part of the question. Reduce the code to the simplest which isn't working.

Comment: E.g. take your first `if-else` condition, how can `print("Hello!")` come outside of  `if`, and similarly `print` statement after `else` how can that be outside of it. Moreover where does `else` end. This holds for all your `if-else` portions.

Comment: Its fine now Thanks..

Comment: As I said, I am brand new to Python, so any help figuring out this while loop would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you need to fix up you indentation and possibly consider tackling this question in a different manner.

To directly answer your question:

```
while word[0].lower() not in "bcdefghjklmnpqrstvwxz":
    word = word[1:] + word[0]
word = word + "ay"
```

you want to add `"ay"` after the loop finishes, or you end up with multiple `"ay"'s`

Here is an example of the loop integrated into a simplified version of your code.

```
VOWELS = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U")
word = raw_input("Please enter a word: ")
if word[0] in VOWELS:
    word = word + "ay"
else:
    while word[0] not in Vowels:
        word = word[1:] + word[0]
    word = word + "ay"
print (word)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try and take this and get better at python, but right now I'm just learning it, so I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I see many problems in your code:
This is redundant `else` condition, also there is `e` in the string:

```
if word0proof in "bcdefghjklmnpqrstvwxyz":
    word1 = word0proof
else:
    word0proof = word0proof
```

The conditions that check for intial letter to be a vowel or consonant can be combined to:

```
if len(word0) > 0 and word0.isalpha():
    word0proof = word0
    if word0proof in "aeiou":
        wordoutput = word + "yay"
            print (wordoutput)
    elif word0proof in "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz":
            word1 = word0proof
```

In your logic to accomplish what you want :

```
while word1 in "bcdefghjklmnpqrstvwxz":
    word1 = word[n:] + word0 + "ay"
    n = n + 1
    print word1
    word1 = word1
```

You are unnecessarily assigning `ay` to end when you still dont know whether the next iteration will have consonant or not. I suggest first you find out how much part of string you want to remove and then add logic to append `ay`. Something like this:

```
cons_index = -1
for index,letter in enumerate(word):
    if letter not  in "bcdefghjklmnpqrstvwxz":
        cons_index = index
        break
your_word = word[cons_index: ]   + word[: cons_index] + "ay"
```

Also dont use too much `variables` it makes your code difficult to understand, e.g. no need of variables `word0` or `word0proof` or `word1`, you can simply access them as `word[0]`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll work on it and take what you said into consideration cause you seem to know what you're talking about, so think you for the help!